# Freeze a date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm pretty new to scripting in Sheets, and I can't get this to work. I have two columns. In column A I want the date to appear and "freeze" in the cell when I fill out the cell next to it in column B, and only then.

I have tried several things, and got inspiration from here: [Freeze a date, once entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525574/freeze-a-date-once-entered), but I can't get it to work. I basically want:

In cell in `A1`: `=IF(ISBLANK(B1), "", TODAY())`

But today is not supposed to be updated unless I change B1.

I've tried:

```
function FreezeDate(String) {
  if (String == "") {
    return ""
  } else {
    return new Date()       
  }
}
```

I've also tried using `OnEdit(String)` with the same body as FreezeDate but this also changes the date when I open the sheet.

Comment: Review existing questions that deal with time-stamping a cell. You want to use an "on edit" simple trigger. You will need to define the situations in which you allow the value to be set. Again, lots of existing questions that deal with exactly that topic.

Comment: Also, please review [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) as `eventObject == ""` (where `eventObject` is defined as `String` in your code) will never be true.

Comment: [tag:timestamp]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?
The date is only added to column one when column two of the same line is edited and column one is blank.  So any further edits of column two do not change the date entry in that row.

```
function insertDateCol1WhenCol2IsEdited(e){//Use with an installable onEdit trigger
  var sheetname='Your Sheet Name'
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!=sheetname){return;}
  if(sh.getName()==sheetname && rg.columnStart==2 && sh.getRange(rg.rowStart,1).isBlank()){
    sh.getRange(rg.rowStart,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried it, but it would not work for me.

Comment: When you say you tried it, did you run it from a trigger? Because this function must be run from a trigger you can’t run it from the script editor because there’s no event or object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response. I thought onEdit(e) had to be given an argument, and that it fired when this was changed. I know see that this is not the case. I think I've figured it out:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var activeCol = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var activeCellValue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();

  // target cell is in same row as active cell and in column 4 (D)
  var targetCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(activeRow, 4)

  // only trigger when change is in column A, when a cell is '-' should not 
  trigger
  if (activeCol == 1 && activeCellValue != '-') {
      targetCell.setValue(new Date())
  } else {
      targetCell.setValue("")
  }
}
```

Comment: your vars `ss`, `activeRow`, `activeCol`, `activeCellValue` are all available from the event object that Google provides when your function is triggered by spreadsheet edits:  `var ss = e.source;`, `var activeCell = e.range;`, `var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();`, `var activeCol = activeCell.getColumn()`. Review the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) documentation. (note that single-cell edits and multi-cell edits generally require consideration in your program logic).